# I cannot set multiple relatives in xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I need to set of my images top off one and another in order to do this I used relative layout what I need is like this menu bar to create in xamarin forms

[image]

so I used code like this in another page and I include it to where ever I want

```
      <RelativeLayout>
    <customRenderes:NavigationImageButton Source="MenuSettings"                                                
                                                      x:Name="Button1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                       Margin="10"
                                                      Opacity="0.4"                                                                                                          
                                     ItemTapped="Button1_OnItemTapped"

                />
    <customRenderes:NavigationImageButton Source="MenuPatientSearch"  RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=Button1,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=10}" 

                                      x:Name="Button2"                                                                                                                                                        
                                      Margin="10"
                                      Opacity="0.4"
                                      ItemTapped="Button1_OnItemTapped"                                                                                                                                                                                                              
/>
    <customRenderes:NavigationImageButton Source="MenuNotifications"  RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=Button2,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=10}" 

                                          x:Name="Button3"                                                                                                                                                           
                                          Margin="10"
                                          Opacity="0.4"
                                          ItemTapped="Button1_OnItemTapped"                                                                                                                                                                      

    />
    <customRenderes:NavigationImageButton Source="MenuShedules"  RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=Button3,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=10}" 

                                          x:Name="Button4"                                                                                                                                                           
                                          Margin="10"
                                          Opacity="0.4"
                                          ItemTapped="Button1_OnItemTapped"                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    />
    <customRenderes:NavigationImageButton Source="menu"  RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=Button4,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=10}" 

                                          x:Name="Button5"                                                                                                                                                              
                                          Margin="10"
                                          Opacity="0.4"
                                          ItemTapped="Button1_OnItemTapped"                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But it only shows to of them one is Menu setting and all other are overlapping in on place How to solve this and I need a view like in that image how to achieve this with or without relative layout.

(I used this code in the custom control and then I exclude it from where ever I need I don't need to compromise that too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way  Can do you adding another stack layout inside the relative layout

```
    <RelativeLayout>
<StackLayout Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical>
    <customRenderes:NavigationImageButton Source="MenuSettings" x:Name="Button1" Margin="10" Opacity="0.4" ItemTapped="Button1_OnItemTapped" />
    <customRenderes:NavigationImageButton Source="MenuPatientSearch"  x:Name="Button2" Margin="10" Opacity="0.4"ItemTapped="Button1_OnItemTapped" />
    <customRenderes:NavigationImageButton Source="MenuNotifications"  x:Name="Button3" Margin="10" Opacity="0.4"ItemTapped="Button1_OnItemTapped" />
    <customRenderes:NavigationImageButton Source="MenuShedules"  x:Name="Button4" Margin="10" Opacity="0.4" ItemTapped="Button1_OnItemTapped"/>
    <customRenderes:NavigationImageButton Source="menu"  x:Name="Button5" Margin="10" Opacity="0.4"ItemTapped="Button1_OnItemTapped" />
</StackLayout>
```